# Finding percentiles in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting

I am writing some code, and I want to know if I am correctly computing percentiles in a sorted array. Currently, if I want to compute, say, the 90th percentile, I do this: ARR[(9 * (N + 1))/10]. Or, let's say I'm computing the 50th percentile in a sorted array, I do this: ARR[(5 * (N + 1)) / 10]. More generally, to compute the xth percentile, I check index [x/100 * (N + 1)], where N is the size of the array.

These seem to be working, but I am just thinking if maybe there is some sort of edge case I'm missing.  For instance, say you only have 5 elements. What should the 90th percentile be then? Should it just be the largest value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, say you only have 5 elements. What should the 90th percentile be then? Should it just be the largest value?

Yes. If you go by a definition like (this one is just copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Definitions))

> the P-th percentile of a list of N ordered values (sorted from least to greatest) is the smallest value in the list such that no more than P percent of the data is strictly less than the value and at least P percent of the data is less than or equal to that value

the 5th element can be the 90th percentile:

- ***no more than P percent of the data is strictly less than the value***: 80% of the data is strictly less than the largest element, which is no more than 90%
- ***at least P percent of the data is less than or equal to that value***: 100% of the data is less than or equal to the 5th element, which is at least 90%

And the 5th element is the smallest one which can do that (even if the 4th and 5th elements are equal, the 5th element is still the smallest one, because the percentile is about the value, not the position).

For fine tuning a formula, border cases are more interesting - like the 79-80-81st percentile of a 5-element list

```
element index:     0       1       2       3       4
strictly less:     0%     20%     40%     60%     80%
less or equal:    20%     40%     60%     80%    100%
```

79th percentile: 4th is expected (60%<79%, 79%<=80%)
80th percentile: 4th is expected (60%<80%, 80%<=80%)
81th percentile: 5th is expected (80%<81%, 81%<=100%)

That feels like rounding something (fraction indices) upwards (knowing that 80 is a border and looking at the mappings 79->3, 80->3, but 81->4). The function is usually called something like `ceil()`, `Math.ceil()` (question specifies no programming language at the moment)

```
 P    5*P/100    ceil(5*P/100)     (5=N)
79      3.95        4
80      4           4
81      4.05        5
```

(`(N+1)` would produce 4.74, 4.8, 4.86, so it is safe to say `+1` is not needed)
And thus `ceil(N*P/100)` really seems to be the one (of course it is on Wikipedia too, just 2-3 lines below the definition)

Note that programming languages may add various quirks:

- arrays/lists are often indexed from 0
- the result of `ceil()` may need to be converted to integer
- and a sneaky one: if `N` and `P` are integer numbers, you may need to ensure that the division is not an integer-division (automatically throwing away the fraction part, so rounding the result downwards).

A Java line would be something like

```
int index=(int)Math.ceil(N*P/100.0)-1;
```

If you want 0th percentile, it can be handled separately, or hacked into the same line with `max()`

```
public static int percentile(int array[],float P) {
  return array[Math.max(0,
    Math.min(array.length, (int)Math.ceil(array.length*P/100))-1)];
}
```

(This one also uses `min()` and will produce some result for any finite `P`, implicitly truncating it into the 0<=P<=100 range)